# Imaplib create folder with spaces

Tags: python-3.x

```
import email, imaplib
import re
import datetime
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
host= "imap.gmail.com"   
username= "ab@gmail.com"
password= "123456"
mail= imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host)
mail.login(username, password)

destination_folder_name = "Emails Processed Jan 2023"
 try:
        mail.create(destination_folder_name)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Unable to create destination Folder: ",e)
```

Is there any solution to create folder in gmail with spaces like folder name "Emails Processed Jan 2023". I am getting the error Unable to create destination Folder:  CREATE command error: BAD [b'Could not parse command']

Answer (score 0):

To create a folder or to call a folder with spaces you just need to create the string like this: `'"Test folder"'`. Note that you need single quotes and double quotes